# Enrichment of slow growing microbes: Large Test Tubes as an alternative?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, archaea

Well, i would like to enrich bacterial and archaeal ammonia oxidisers from soil samples using Minimal Salt media. They are slow growing microbes. I would like to enrich them with the aim to produce pure cultures.

I have always used conical flasks for enrichment as they provide better aeration, surface area, better distribution of nutrients, etc. However, due to some unavoidable reason, i would like to find an alternative to conical flask. Is it fine to use large test tubes?

Comment: I can't think of any reason slant cultures wouldn't work. It's worth a try!

Comment: @jzx agar slants in the sense solid media? i would like to use broth (not solid media), may be i can keep the broth in a slant position?

Comment: Yes, that was my thought. Obviously not ideal since you'll have to be careful, but if that's all you have on hand it's what I would do.

Comment: You want to purify colonies by growing them and streaking? You can use larger test tubes with sufficient air volume (use around 5ml of broth in 20 ml test tube) and proper mixing.

Comment: @WYSIWYG, ya, i want to grow them in a selective broth and then get pure culture if possible. Many Literature from NCBI using 50 ml broth (minimal salt media) in a 150 ml Erlenmeyer flask. And since the Ammonia oxidizers grow real slow, the media is replaced (10% dispensed in fresh media) weekly.

Comment: @NokImchen can you not provide an enriching medium?